# AWS Cognito prevent creating duplicate phone number

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

While registering users in AWS Cognito user pool we are choosing the option to "allow email addresses" as the username to sign up and sign in. In the required attributes there is also phone number. But the same phone number can be used again for another user, while the email id is unique. Is there any way to stop the phone number being duplicated,so that both the phone number and email id is unique for each user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Pre-Signup Lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html) to check whether the phone number is already in use and handle accordingly.